# PHP Trait Singleton

Tags: php, php5, singleton, trait

An implementation of the singleton pattern in PHP using a trait (added in 5.4). Is there anything missing, any ways to create a second copy of the class?

```
trait Singleton {
    static function instance() {
        static $instance;
        if ( is_null( $instance ) ) {
            $instance = new static;
        }
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

A class can the `use` the `trait` with the following:

```
class P {
    use Singleton;
    protected function __construct() {
        echo 'Hello, parent!' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    final private function __clone() {}
}

class C extends P {
    protected function __construct() {
        echo 'Hello, child!' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

echo get_class( P::instance() ) . PHP_EOL;
echo get_class( C::instance() ) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

> ```
> Hello, parent!
> P
> Hello, child!
> C
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Contract Enforcement

There are a few ways to violate the singleton contract, but none need to be guarded against.

1. Create a subclass with a public constructor. This obviously is pilot error.
2. Use reflection to either make the constructor accessible (5.3.2) or instantiate the class without calling the constructor (5.5?).
3. Serialization. I think private `__sleep` and `__wake` methods would block this.

However, these are active attacks, and the contract should only concern itself with preventing mistakes. So in that regard this looks sufficient.

### Configurability

You may want to consider accepting arguments and passing them to the constructor (if this is even possible using `new static`).

For example, a database connection could accept the host, port, user, and password, allowing reuse in many applications. Otherwise each program must subclass the connection to supply its connection info.

Again, I don't know if this is even possible. I think the only way to pass an array of parameters to a constructor is via reflection, and I don't know if you can get the correct subclass name staticly.

### Minor Tip

Since `$instance` is either `null` (falsey) or a valid instance (truthy), you can simplify

```
if (is_null($instance)) . . .
```

to

```
if (!$instance) . . .
```

### Testability

This implementation will make testing difficult. Moving the static local variable to a private static property would allow clearing it using reflection in a unit test.

Answer (score 4):

From the get-go, let's agree that `static` and the Singleton pattern are quite pointless in PHP. By design, PHP is a stateless language. The state of an object is *not* retained in between requests. Hence, `static` is often referred to as mere globals in OO-drag.
I would like to stress that, in PHP, Singletons are as pointless as a broken pencil.

Be that as at it may, a `Singleton` trait is an interesting thought. It's a good way to visualize, test and eventually understand inheritance precedence, when traits are involved. And it can also show how magic constants and certain keywords behave unexpectedly.
But it's nothing more than that: an academic example, an exercise and... *an example of bad practices*.

***Don't abuse traits***

What you do is very bad practice indeed. You take a concept, meant to do one thing, and abuse it to do something entirely different. You're using a trait, not to get around the (alleged) limitations of single inheritance to mimic multiple inheritance.

## This is not what a trait is for

Ask yourself: *"What is the point of a trait?"*, why were the introduced? They were created to solve (IMHO imagined) problems, posed by single inheritance (which actually is a good thing). Traits are an attempt to offer the benefits of multiple inheritance without all of the headaches. A trait is a unit of code that *extends the functionality of a class*. You are using a trait to *dictate the behaviour and usage of a class*.

Consider the syntax:

```
class Bar extends Foo{}
```

Ok, a class that builds on a fully-fledged (stand-alone) class. The `extends` keyword makes sense.
Now:

```
class Something implements Iterator{}
```

A class, that implements an interface. The interface dictates (part of) the behaviour and can be used to enforce a contract. A class that implements an interface has to conform. Just like JavaScript is an *implementation* of the ECMAScript standard, and compilers ship with an *implementation* of the C/C++ standard, so must this class be *an implementation of the interface's contract*.
Again, the keyword `implements` covers the load.

Look at the syntax for traits, though:

```
Class Something extends Base implements Iterator
{
    use DBGetters;
}
```

The `use` statement is part of the class, it does not belong to the class definition. A trait, then, has no business enforcing a contract in the way an (abstract) parent class does. Nor should it dictate the behaviour of a class, like an interface does.

Everything you have (Classes, interfaces and traits) are meant to address a specific issue you might encounter.
A trait *adds* functionality. It does ***not*** change the way a class functions.
By this stage, you may have guessed that I'm not a huge fan of traits. I'm not completely against them, *if used correctly*. But PHP has given far too much power to traits, but at the same time, the using class is free to override certain aspects of a trait, which makes for very confusing situations. Classes can choose to rename methods that a trait defines, they're free to change the visibility of trait methods (turn `public` into `protected`), and they can resolve name conflicts by simply renaming a given method, take the following piece of code:

```
trait Foo
{
    public function traitMethod()
    {
        return 'I am public';
    }

    public function duplicateMethod()
    {
        return 'I am defined in trait Foo';
    }
}
trait Bar
{
    protected function duplicateMethod()
    {
        return 'I am defined in trait Bar';
    }
}
class TraitMess
{
    use Foo, Bar {
        Foo::traitMethod as protected;
        Bar::duplicateMethod insteadof Foo;
        Foo::duplicateMethod as renamedMethod;
    }
}
```

Now imagine that you have a method/function somewhere that checks what traits are implemented by a given object, and uses that information to call certain methods. After all: if an object implements trait X, it should be a reasonable assumption to make that you can call the methods of that trait, no? Not quite:

```
function checkTrait(TraitMess $obj)
{
    $traitsUsed = class_uses($obj);
    if (isset($tratsUsed['Foo']))
    {
        //we don't know about $obj->renamedMethod at all, so:
        echo $obj->duplicateMethod();//expected I am defined in trait Foo, whereas it actually echoes "I am defined in trait Bar"!
        echo $obj->traitMethod();//<-- error, trait defines as public, but is implemented as protected
    }
}
```

So, even if a class uses a trait, there's really no way of knowing what that class has done with that trait. At all. If it implements multiple traits, the way conflicts are resolved is a total unknown. The only thing you can do than, is to use an (expensive) `ReflectionClass` instance and the trusty `get_class_methods` or `get_object_vars` functions.

So what **is** a valid use-case for a trait? Well, to me, the only reasonable use-cases for a trait is to avoid duplication of getters/setters and other simple methods:

```
trait EmailData
{
    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $email = null;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     * @return $this
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        if (!filter_var($email, \FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf(
                    '"%s" is not a valid email address',
                    $email
                )
            );
        }
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

That's a trait that doesn't meddle with the actual functionality of a class too much, it's just something that helps you to ensure that all of your models that contain email addresses validate them in the same way.

Still, some core-review:

The issues up front:

- try to adhere to the [coding standards](http://www.php-fig.org) as much as possible
- ***always*** specify an access modifier, don't rely on the implicit `public`. Someone might come across some code, and treat the lack of an access modifier as an error, and make it `protected`.
- static methods begin with an UpperCase
- constructors can, and generally should, take arguments
- To ensure a method is not overwritten in child classes, use the `final` keyword
- Initializing variables is a good habit. Though not required in PHP (default value is null), it's a habit that makes the transition to other languages easier/smoother. Initialize to `null` explicitly

Let's put all this to practice when writing your trait.

```
trait Singleton
{
    final public static function GetInstance(array $args = null)
    {
        static $instance = null;
        if ( is_null( $instance ) ) {
            $instance = new static($args);
        }
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

That, to my eye, looks a lot cleaner, but there are problems. With this code, your *trait* is implicitly enforcing a contract: the `__construct` methods will now be passed either `null` or an array, and so all constructors must be defined to conform to this contract.
The static variable that retains the instance is a static variable is also local to the method's scope. I know why you do this, but there are implications, and alternatives. One such implication is (owing to PHP's memory management system, which relies on simple ref-counts), that the instance will not be eligible for garbage collection (most static's aren't, for the same reason).
However, a regular singleton class, in PHP does allow for its ref-count to be set to 0, and can be garbage collected (in a hacky way):

```
class GCSingleton
{
    private static $Instance = null;
    //private constructor and such
    final public static function GetInstance()
    {
        if (self::$Instance === null)//or static::$Instance
            self::$Instance = new static;
        return self::$Instance;
    }
    public function selfDestruct()
    {
        self::$Instance = null;
        return null;
    }
}
$singleton = GCSingleton::GetInstance();
$singleton = $singleton->selfDestruct();
```

This only works, though, if no other variable references the instance in question, but no matter.

Of course, I completely understand why you did not create a property to which you assign the instance. A static instance is, after all, shared, so using a static property makes inheritance impossible, right?
Not quite: enter inheritance precedence. You can override a static property in a child class, with the same (or less) restrictions:

```
trait Test
{
    private static $Inst = null;
    final public static function GetInstance()
    {
        if (static::$Inst === null)
            static::$Inst = new static;
        return static::$Inst;
    }
}
class Foo
{
    use Test;
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Created new instance of ', __CLASS__, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
class Bar extends Foo
{
    protected static $Inst = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Created instance of ', __CLASS__, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$foo = Foo::GetInstance();//echoes Created instance of Foo
$bar = Bar::GetInstance();//echoes Created instance of Bar
```

If, however, you change the use of the keyword `static` to `self`, you loose the power of *late static bindings*, and `Bar::GetInstance` returns the instance of `Foo`, assigned to the private property of the trait.

Ok, now that's some under-the-hood info of how the properties are being resolved, and how the resources are managed. Let's move on to some actual code-review:

***Omissions***

The whole point of singletons is that they are there to make sure you never create more than one single instance of a given class. You are aware of the `__clone` magic method, but you're missing the `__sleep` and `__wakeup`, or even the `__toString` methods.
The best way to address this issue, IMO, is to define all of them (as `final`) in the trait, and instead of letting them fail silently, have them throw exceptions. The moment someone writes something like:

```
$copy = clone $singleton;
```

An exception should be thrown. You're just assigning null to `$copy`, which won't produce errors until someone uses this `$copy` variable as an object. This can lead to hours, wasted on debugging code, looking for that statement that reassigns `$copy`, that just isn't there. Instead, write something like:

```
final public function __clone()
{
    throw new LogicException(
        sprintf(
            'Error: cloning of %s instances is not alllowed',
             get_class($this)
        )
    );
}
```

Do this for *all* magic methods.

Comment: `PHP is a stateless language` what if I was running an event loop using PHP and a library such as https://github.com/reactphp/react?

Comment: Then a static would still be a global in OO drag, wouldn't it? I don't see the difference between a global instance (or one passed to a callback using `function () use ($instance)`) and a singleton in that case, and seeing as react scripts never shut down, why not simply keep a normally created instance in scope? Why bother using `GetInstance`, if you can assign it to a variable in the first place? you're right, of course, but then again, react isn't quite the most common use-case for PHP ATM...

Comment: Even so, react doesn't change the statelessness of PHP. The state is retained for as long as the script runs, When the process ends, all state is lost. The _"trick"_ that react uses is just to open socket-streams, make them non-blocking and check their status in a loop. Those socket streams aren't singletons either, they're simple objects, too

Comment: Yes, you're right too. However, I was actually getting more at the need / use of singletons in PHP. Was really picking at straws with that example but thought it was relevant enough to mention it. Despite that, you could argue that no language is stateful, only the data it stores/consumes about its state is relevant. In that case PHP is no different.

Comment: @DavidBarker: I get your point, but what I'm thinking of goes beyond data storage. In C or Java, you can write a piece of software that receives a request, gets data from a DB connection, and sends a request, without that program having to close/open that DB connection for each request. Things like connection pooling are common in Java or C applications. Not so much in PHP. That's what I'm actually thinking of when I say that, unlike some langauges, PHP is truly stateless (it's a gray area, and I'm ignoring hhvm and php-fpm + persistent connections, but you know what I mean...)

Comment: There is nothing 'pointless' about singletons in PHP. Case in point: 

https://ttmm.io/tech/the-case-for-singletons/

Comment: @unity100: I'm sorry, but wordpress is hardly the pinnacle of good design. That post basically argues in favour of singletons because it doesn't rely on the evil `global` keyword that is overused. I'd argue that, if singletons are better, that just goes to show how bad the code of wordpress is.

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem that "Bad design" is running 20% of websites on internet, ranging from ecommerce applications to social networks, to CNN, Reuters websites. That IS good design. That it may not fit into the currently 'popular' paradigm does not change that reality... If you are that disturbed by wordpress, wait until 'functional programming' takes off...

Comment: @unity100: I like functional programming languages. JavaScript is functional, I like it. Scheme is great fun. Wordpress is moving to node.js anyway, probably because they weighed the pro's and con's of what it would take to fix the problems they have in their current code base. The argument that 20% of the web is powered by something in BS. At one point, the majority of people believed illnesses were caused by demons. That doesn't make it right.